# How to format badly structured URL with UriBuilder?

Tags: c#, parsing, uri

I am currently running through a CSV that has a column that is a designated URL.

I am using the URLs to pull data from a specific endpoint.

My current method is to parse the host of the URI, to send to my endpoint is the following:

```
public static Uri GetURI(string s)
{
    return new UriBuilder(s).Uri;
}

if ( websiteLoc > -1 ) {
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row[websiteLoc]))
    {
        Uri uri = GetURI(row[websiteLoc]);
        record.Add("website", uri.Host);
    } else {
        record.Add("website", "");
    }
}
```

However the URLs has the potential to be badly formatted/structured/typed due to human error of the people inputting the URL.

Ive run into extremely poorly formatted URLs in the column such as:

```
htpp://www.sessler.cm.utexas.edu/
http //www.fedex.com
http.redhead-int.com
http:://www.741limo.com/
```

In these instances my code has either incorrectly parsed the correct Host or thrown an error. Is there a better way to attempt to parse these horrible URLs correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You'll get tons of false negatives/positives if you rely on Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(), but...

You can also use a combination of REGEX and/or string comparisons to try to increase your valid URL hitrate. Note that I use char comparisons in some places where Regex would be much nicer. I'm trying to show that you can do either REGEX or direct comparison.

Tighter REGEX and/or additional logic could produce better results. This won't produce a 100% hitrate, but it will clean up a number of poorly-typed URLs. Note that REGEX requires a reference to System.Text.RegularExpressions:

```
private List<int> acceptableChars = new List<int>();
    private void createListOfAcceptableCharacters()
    {

        List<int> acceptableChars = new List<int>();
        acceptableChars.Add(45);// -
        acceptableChars.Add(46);// .
        acceptableChars.Add(47);// /
        for (int a = 97; a < 123; a++)
        {// a through z
            acceptableChars.Add(a);
        }
        for (int a = 48; a < 58; a++)
        {//0 through 9
            acceptableChars.Add(a);
        }
    } 
    public string parseURL(string input)
    {//you would only do this once in reality
        createListOfAcceptableCharacters();
        //basic cleanup
        input = input.ToLower();
        //Regex.Replace would be more elegant here but string.replace works, too
        input = input.Replace(".cm", ".com").Replace("htpp","http").Replace("htp", "http").Replace("http.", "http:").Replace("//ww.", "//www.").Replace(":/", "://").Replace(":////", "://").Replace(":///", "://").Replace(" ","");
        //check to see if URL is generally valid as-is
        bool isValid = isValidURL(input); 
        if (isValid)
        {
            return input;
        }
        //try to salvage a poorly formed URL
        bool isSecure = input.Substring(0, 5).IndexOf("https") > -1 ? true : false;
        input = input.Replace(" ","").Replace(":","").Replace("https","").Replace("http//", "").Replace("http/", "").Replace("http", "").Replace("http", "").Replace("//","").Replace("www","").Replace("ww","").Replace("cm","com");//again, regex.replace would be more elegant
        //clear front end to first period if it exists before space 6
        if (input.IndexOf(".") < 7)
        {
            int period = input.IndexOf(".");
            input = input.Substring(period+1);
        }
        //get the extension
        string extension = "";
        if (input.Substring(input.Length - 1) == "/")
        {
            input = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1);
        }
        if (input.Substring(input.Length - 4, 1) == ".")
        {
            //extension is where we expect
            extension = input.Substring(input.Length - 3, 3);
            input = input.Replace("." + extension, "");
        }else
        {
            //cannot find extension - can't process
            return "badURL";
        }
        string url = "";
        //move backwars through path, collecting only acceptable characters (note, this can be done with REGEX as well)
        for (int i = input.Length-1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            string thisChar = input.Substring(i, 1);
            if (thisChar == ":")
            {
                return "http://" + url + "." + extension;
            }
            int utf = (int)Convert.ToChar(thisChar);

            //compare current char to list of acceptable chars
            if (acceptableChars.Contains(utf))
            {
                url = thisChar+url;
            }

        }
        //final cleanup and full path formation
        if (url.Substring(0, 1) == ".")
        {
            url = url.Substring(1);
        }
        url = isSecure ? "https://" : "http://" + url + "." + extension;
        //optional
        url = isSecure ? "https://www." : "http://www." + url + "." + extension;
        url = url.Replace("::", ":");
        //test salvaged url. If reasonable, return else return badURL
       if (isValidURL(url))
        {
            return url;
        }else
        {
            return "badURL";
        }


    }

    private bool isValidURL(string url)
    {
        bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(url, @"^((http[s]?:[/][/])?(\w+[\-.])+com|((http[s]?:[/][/])?(\w+[\-.])+com[/]|[.][/])?\w+([/]\w+)*([/]|[.]html|[.]php|[.]gif|[.]jpg|[.]png)?)$");
        return isValid;

    }
```

I might suggest amending the parse method to return the "fixed" url instead of "badURL" -- sometimes it will fix a URL that is actually valid but gets a false rejection by the RegEx. Rather than handling the return of "badURL," you could try to access the URL and handle any errors there.

**PLEASE NOTE** - this is by no means intended to represent a final, working solution. You'll have to test and amend with multiple inputs and clean/optimize the code accordingly. It's only intended as an example to demonstrate the use of both string comparisons and Regex in trying to clean up URLs.